# Test Method 'X' threw exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Mapper not initialized. Call Initialize with appropriate configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, automapper

Here is the code for the method that I'm developing the unit test for:

```
public ActionResult ItemsListing()
{
    var itemsList = itemsRepository.GetItems(true);

    if (itemsList.Count() > 0)
    {
        var itemsListVMs = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Item>, IEnumerable<itemsListingViewModel>>(itemsList);
        return View(itemsListVMs);
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Home");
    }

}
```

Following is the code from the mapping configuration file:

```
public static class MappingConfig
{
    public static void RegisterMaps()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(config =>
        {
            config.CreateMap<Item, itemsListingViewModel>();
        });
    }
}
```

And I have initialized mapper in the `Application_Start()` event of the `Global.asax` as below:

```
MappingConfig.RegisterMaps();
```

Below is the simple test method that I'm trying to run:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ItemsListing()
{
    HomeController controller = new HomeController();

    ViewResult result = controller.ItemsListing() as ViewResult;

    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
}
```

It works fine when I simply run the application. But when I try to run the unit test method, it shows the mentioned error message. Can anyone help me to get over this issue? Thanks!

Comment: What test framework are you using, MSTest?

Comment: @LukeW: Yes, it is MSTest.

Comment: @user1990, Are you calling `MappingConfig.RegisterMaps();` in your unit tests?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create/register the mappings for your unit tests as well as the `Application_Start()` is not executed. It is associated with IIS, which is not running during unit tests. You have to manually call the mapping configurations.

```
[TestClass]
public class HomeControllerTests {
    [ClassInitialize]
    public static void Init(TestContext context) {
        MappingConfig.RegisterMaps();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ItemsListing() {
        HomeController controller = new HomeController();

        ViewResult result = controller.ItemsListing() as ViewResult;

        Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    }
}
```

In the above test the mapping configuration is done in a method decorated with `[ClassInitialize]` attribute which

> [ClassInitializeAttribute Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.classinitializeattribute.aspx)
>   Identifies a method that contains code that must be used before any of
>   the tests in the test class have run and to allocate resources to be
>   used by the test class.

Comment: You might want to go into a little detail about `[TestInitialize]`. It's important to know that it causes that chunk of code to be run once before every test in that class.

Comment: @Nkosi : Thank you very much! Although, I needed to declare the Init() method as static and pass a parameter of type TestContext to it. Now it is working perfectly!